# How to render a custom {{element}} from an ng-repeated list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

Trying to get angular to render a list of directives after a drop-down is toggled in bootstrap.

Ideally, I'll $scope in the main view Ctrl:

```
$scope.directiveList = ['messages', 'events', 'cart'];
```

and in the html

```
<div ng-repeat="directive in directive-list">
  <{{directive}}/>
</div>
```

the results i'm getting are plain text, i.e. . I've tried to modify another helper directive I learned that renders normal html elements fine but doesn't render custom expressions. Here's that directive code:

```
.directive("notify", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"EA",
        scope:{element:"="},
        link:function(scope, iElem) {
            var domElement = document.createElement(scope.element);
            iElem.append(domElement);

        }
    };
});
```

This code renders the element in plain text as well tho it doesn't show in the view. Any help, as always, is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile - this actually is for things like this - you can do something like `$compile(iElem)(scope)`

Comment: Thanks, this is the right path. The directive is rendering! Any idea of an elegant way to pass in the scope from the view controller without using a service? Tried passing in $parent to the directive but nope.

Comment: When removing `scope:{}` your directive will use the parent scope - maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482 :)

Comment: i'll digest this. i've been a bit lazy understanding isolate scope and just relied on the view controller. learning to componentize my code more. thanks much!